# All routes return 404 when deploying on server laravel+nuxt+nginx

Tags: node.js, laravel, nginx, nuxt.js, laravel-6.2

Im trying to upload **both** Laravel 6.2 as a backend And Nuxt 2.11 as frontend (universal mode) into a server but after  upload every routes returns laravel 404, Im am also using nginx reverse proxy (production mode)

Using this laravel-nuxt package https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt

**Upload Steps**

1- upload backend files and folders ( app,bootstrap,client,config,database,routes,storage,vendor,package.json and lock,composer.json and lock)

2-upload frontend files and folders(.nuxt, and everything insdie my client folder)

3-In my server Ive added a new line at the end of my nginx.conf  `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;`

4- then in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled I have default.conf with the following content

```
server {
  # server on port 80 (default http port)
  listen 80;
  server_name rabter.com;

  # proxy for frontend
  location / {
    # nuxt server url
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  # proxy for api
  location /api/* {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    # laravel server url
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Enable my Server Blocks and Restart Nginx
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

5- Ill setup pm2 server so I run pm2 start Laravel-nuxt to start listening to port 3000 ( lunching nuxt)

At this point I access my site which returns 404 on all routes no exception
I also came across this https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-nuxt/issues/1#issuecomment-491484474
which I think it essentially what I want to do even tried the nginx code but didnt work

I have 0 routes in my web.php and all the routes are in api.php.Also this project works fine on localhost both dev and prod mode but when I move to the server its all 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right configuration file for ssl 
The http Configuration File

```
server {
  listen your-server-ip:80;
    server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}
```

The ssl configuration file

```
server {
  listen your-server-ip:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}
server {
    listen your-server-ip:443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.com.bundle;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/example.com.key;
      root /home/example/core/public/;
        index index.php;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.bytes bytes;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log combined;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log error;

location / {

    proxy_set_header                Connection "keep-alive";
    proxy_set_header                Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header                Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_http_version              1.1;
    proxy_pass                      https://your-server-ip:3000$uri;
    proxy_intercept_errors          on;# In order to use error_page directive this needs to be on
    error_page                      404 = @php;
}

location @php {
    try_files                       $uri $uri/  /index.php?$query_string;

}

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass                    your-server-ip:9000;
    fastcgi_index                   index.php;
    include                         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size             16k;
    fastcgi_buffers                 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
   fastcgi_send_timeout            300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout            300;
}
}
```

**Keep in mind my port was `3000` yours might be different**

**fastcgi_pass can be poiting to a sock too but I directly added it**

**fastcgi_pass port is set to 9000 in my case Yours can be different**

with those being said , We are redirecting 80 and 433 **without www** to **www** and then doing a reverse proxy , if the reverse proxy is 404 we try @php and at bottom we are using php-fpm to run our php code

I almost spent 2 weeks learning nginx and writing different configuration till I cameup with this one